# Make default Ionic alerts larger

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm trying to make the default Ionic Alerts larger. I'm developing an app that needs to have easy touch points and the default alerts are too small for what I'm needing.

I've tried enlarging the font as well as expanding the width of the alerts but nothing seems to actually make the alerts larger.

Any easy/best ways to do this?

Comment: Did you try to do that using custom css style which alerts controller supports?

Comment: I tried adding this to the CSS

.alertCustomCss{
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    button{
        color: green!important;
    }
    .alert-wrapper{
        background: yellow;
    }
    .alert-message {
        color: skyblue;
    }
    .alert-title{
        color: black;
    }
}

then added this class to the alert which worked.

But I had no luck adding anything for sizing and getting the page to reflect it. I'm basically wanting to take what it currently displays and just make it larger (font, width, etc)

Comment: I can see when I inspect the element the following code line:

<div class="alert-wrapper" style="opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);">

if I change that to 3 in the browser it appears to enlarge like I want it to.

I added this to my app.scss file but it still shows as 3 in the browser and not 1

.alert{

    .alert-wrapper{
        background: lightskyblue;
        transform: scale(3);
    }

  
}

Answer (score 2):

AlertController supports custom classes which could be placed in your component's scss file and there you can do necessary alterations.

For example in your component's ts file you can have this method that creates alert with reference to custom class "scaledAlert":

```
delete() {
    let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: "Are You Sure?",
      cssClass: "scaledAlert",
      message: "this will remove image from your image gallery",
      buttons: [
        {
          text: "Cancel",
          handler: () => {
            console.log("Canceled delete");
          }
        },
        {
          text: "Confirm",
          handler: () => {
            console.log("deleting...");
            this.deleteImageFromGallery(this.image)
              .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
              })
              .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
              });
            this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    confirm.present();
  }
```

Now in the scss file you add class to style as you need to scale the controller, such class goes after your page or component:

```
home-page {
    .item {
        min-height: 2rem; /* <- this can be whatever you need */
    }
    ion-label {
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0;
    }
    .item-content {
        padding-top: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        margin-top: -12px;
        margin-bottom: -12px;
        height: 50px;
    }
}
.scaledAlert {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

Here I used just naive "scale" function which may require you to add some cross browser compatible versions of it. But you should achieve what you want with it (it worked in my app without issues).

Alternatively you can override default styles using saas variables: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/alert/AlertController/#sass-variables

You will have to alter them in theme\variables.scss" which is located in your project's folder

See more here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/

And third option is indeed to check elements' style via devtool and attempt to override those classes. But I don't like that way, feels a bit more hacky.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the styles for alert are not getting updated if written in component SCSS file. The styles need to be written in the global scss file.

Comment: styles for alert need to be written in global scss file since alert is beyond the scope of component.